# Gulp override manually added dependencies

Tags: gulp, dependencies

I'm building webapp and I need ngmap. So I've installed it with bower and it included it in my index.html.
Problem is that I need `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey"></script>`
I add it manually but every time I run `gulp build`, it override my *index.html*.

How to solve that?

I also have problem with some libraries that cannot be installed with *bower* so I download it manually. I don't know how to include them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just added `<script...` outside of `<!-- bower:js -->`tag, or any other 'special' tag, and it stays.